# How to create light Eclipse RCP container for JavaScript, and HTML5+JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, html, node.js, eclipse-rcp

In [Nodeclipse project](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/) Node.js IDE based on IDE, naturally development goes with Java.
I heard that Eclipse had plan to let use JavaScript for form validation etc.,
but I want radical approach: just run every components in WebView and use Eclipse RCP abstraction like Editor, View to connect them all.

**How to create light Eclipse RCP [container for JavaScript](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/JavaScriptContainer), and HTML5+JavaScript?**

I mean something more than just raw WebView widget.
Some Internet resources to the topic and directions for research are wanted.

Comment: There is also SWT SWT html browser class (org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser). And, please, take a look at Vaaclipse project: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html#alternativerenderer_own1

Comment: Vaaclipse - That is amazing to have your Eclipse Java code in browser (actually Vaadin is now using GWT). However it is not answer to Q how include JavaScript into Eclipse-RCP.

Comment: Look through themes like this one: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/372724/ - you can do much (HTML5 & JS1.5) with SWT browser and XUL runner.